# Data in LoLiMot sub-spaces have linear distribution or gaussian?

Tags: neural-network

I'm confused that lolimot approximate data by sum of linear models or by some of gaussian models? I see here on page 184 that lolimot is a model for dividing space into linear sub-spaces, but structure of lolimot is sum ofweighted gaussian models. Actually I mean data in every subspace have linear distribution or gaussian distribution?
Thanks